# Regex to match URL and specify an href with the matched URL

Tags: regex

I have a log that has the following url:

```
https://<hostname>/<directory>/builds/<job>/<version>/<build_number>
```

where:

```
hostname = any valid hostname
directory = any valid directory
job = any valid collection of characters (it may contain '-')
version = [0-9].[0-9] (i.e.) 1.0
build_number = [0-9] (i.e.) 2012050677
```

My intent is to read the log and use a regex to do the following:

1. match the url
2. set an href using the url as follows:

   ```
   <a href=matched_url>Latest build</a>
   ```

What kind of regex can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a regex replace of

```
https://[^/]+/[^/]+/builds/[^/]+/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/\d+
```

with

```
<a href='$&'>Latest build</a>
```

Alternatively `$0` instead of `$&`, depending on your regex engine, probably.